# Android - out of memory exception at view creation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm try to use the MaterialViewPager [library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager).
Every time i run my application i get the following exception. There is no reference to my own code.

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 6586008 byte
> allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 4MB until OOM"
>
> Error reporting crash
>
> at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
> at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
> ....

After debugging i found out that my code stops at the following lines (OverviewPagerFragment - full code see below)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Pager", "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_pager, container, true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

For your help here is my full code of my "OverviewActivity". The first activity just replace the FrameLayout with "OverviewFragment". It is pretty the same code as the sample code of the library but i don't know the exception is throwing...

```
public class OverviewFragment extends BaseFragment<OverviewView, OverviewPresenter> {

    @Bind(R.id.material_view_pager)
    MaterialViewPager materialViewPager;

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_overview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("OverviewFragment", "onActivityCreated");
        materialViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Log.d("OverviewFragment", "getItem");
                return new OverviewPagerFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                Log.d("OverviewFragment", "getCount");
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Log.d("OverviewFragment", "getPageTitle");
                switch (position % 4) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Eins";
                    case 1:
                        return "Zwei";
                    case 2:
                        return "Drei";
                    case 3:
                        return "Vier";
                }

                return "";
            }
        });

        materialViewPager.getViewPager()
                .setOffscreenPageLimit(materialViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount());
        materialViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(materialViewPager.getViewPager());
    }
}



public class OverviewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Bind(R.id.recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Pager", "onCreateView");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_pager, container, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Pager", "onViewCreated");
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new OverviewAdapter());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), recyclerView, null);
    }
}


public class OverviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("Adapter", "getItemCount");
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("Adapter", "obCreateViewH");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.overview_item_list, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){};
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me? I tried to find my mistake for hours.. Thanks

Comment: by any chance, do you have a large image being loaded? by large, I mean in dimensions, not file size.

Comment: Nope. No image or anything else. I just want to test the library with static texts.. small text.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

Change your line:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_pager, container, true);
```

to:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_pager, container, false);
```